# Add table columns correctly in rails 4

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I'm writing a simple rails app which has users,projects and tasks.
And I have the next problem: each user must have his own projects,and each projects must have it's own tasks.When I'm trying to debug my app via console I can see that  projects and tasks are created without "user_id" and "project_id".So my DB was configurated incorrectly and because of app doesn't work correctly(columns weren't add to Projects and Tasks tables and because of it  app simply can't create projects,that will belong to only one user and tasks which belong to only one project.(and that's the main point of the app)
Can someone help me to deal with my models and migrations,cause I'me really stuck with this stuff

Here are the corresponding models and migrations

Project.rb

```
class Project < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :user
  has_many :tasks, dependent: :destroy
  validates :name, presence: true, uniqueness: true
end
```

User.rb

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :tasks, through: :projects, dependent: :destroy
  has_many :projects, dependent: :destroy
  attr_accessor :remember_token
  before_save { self.email = email.downcase }
  validates :name,  presence: true, length: { maximum: 50 }
  VALID_EMAIL_REGEX = /\A[\w+\-.]+@[a-z\d\-.]+\.[a-z]+\z/i
  validates :email, presence: true, length: { maximum: 255 },
                    format: { with: VALID_EMAIL_REGEX },
                    uniqueness: { case_sensitive: false }
  has_secure_password
  validates :password, presence: true, length: { minimum: 6 }, allow_nil: true

  # Returns the hash digest of the given string.
  def User.digest(string)
    cost = ActiveModel::SecurePassword.min_cost ? BCrypt::Engine::MIN_COST :
                                                  BCrypt::Engine.cost
    BCrypt::Password.create(string, cost: cost)
  end

  # Returns a random token.
  def User.new_token
    SecureRandom.urlsafe_base64
  end

  # Remembers a user in the database for use in persistent sessions.
  def remember
    self.remember_token = User.new_token
    update_attribute(:remember_digest, User.digest(remember_token))
  end

  # Returns true if the given token matches the digest.
  def authenticated?(remember_token)
    return false if remember_digest.nil?
    BCrypt::Password.new(remember_digest).is_password?(remember_token)
  end

  # Forgets a user
  def forget
    update_attribute(:remember_digest, nil)
  end
end
```

Task.rb

```
class Task < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :project
end
```

Migration for creating projects

```
class CreateProjects < ActiveRecord::Migration
  def change
    create_table :projects do |t|
      t.string :name

      t.timestamps null: false
    end
  end
end
```

And for creating tasks

```
class CreateTasks < ActiveRecord::Migration
  def change
    create_table :tasks do |t|
      t.string :name
      t.datetime :deadline

      t.timestamps null: false
    end
  end
end
```

Now when I try to create/update/delete a new task I always get some errors like[image]

Also here are the corresponding controllers,maybe something also wrong there

projects_controller.rb

```
class ProjectsController < ApplicationController
  before_action :find_project!, only: [ :update, :destroy]

  # GET /projects
  # GET /projects.json
  def index
    @projects = current_user.projects
    @project  = Project.new
  end

  # GET /projects/1
  # GET /projects/1.json
  def show
  end

  # GET /projects/new
  def new
    @project = Project.new
  end

  # GET /projects/1/edit
  def edit
  end

  # POST /projects
  # POST /projects.json
  def create
    @project = current_user.projects.create(project_params)

    respond_to do |format|
      if @project.save
        format.html { redirect_to home_url }
        format.json { render :show, status: :created, location: @project }
      else
        format.html { render :home_url }
        format.json { render json: @project.errors, status: :unprocessable_entity }
      end
    end
  end

  # PATCH/PUT /projects/1
  # PATCH/PUT /projects/1.json
  def update
    respond_to do |format|
      if @project.update(project_params)
        format.html { redirect_to home_url }
        format.json { render :show, status: :ok, location: @project }
      else
        format.html { render :home_url }
        format.json { render json: @project.errors, status: :unprocessable_entity }
      end
    end
  end

  # DELETE /projects/1
  # DELETE /projects/1.json
  def destroy
    @project.destroy
    respond_to do |format|
      format.html { redirect_to home_url }
      format.json { head :no_content }
    end
  end

  private
    # Use callbacks to share common setup or constraints between actions

    def find_project!
      @project = current_user.projects.find(params[:id])
    end

    # Never trust parameters from the scary internet, only allow the white list through.
    def project_params
      params.require(:project).permit(:name)
    end
end
```

tasks_controller.rb

```
class TasksController < ApplicationController
  before_action :set_task, only: [:show, :edit, :update, :destroy]

  # GET /tasks
  # GET /tasks.json
  def index
    @tasks = Task.all
  end

  # GET /tasks/1
  # GET /tasks/1.json
  def show
  end

  # GET /tasks/new
  def new
    @task = Task.new
  end

  # GET /tasks/1/edit
  def edit
  end

  # POST /tasks
  # POST /tasks.json
  def create
    @task = @project.tasks.create(task_params)

    respond_to do |format|
      if @task.save
        format.html { redirect_to home_url }
        format.json { render :show, status: :created, location: @task }
      else
        format.html { render :home_url }
        format.json { render json: @task.errors, status: :unprocessable_entity }
      end
    end
  end

  # PATCH/PUT /tasks/1
  # PATCH/PUT /tasks/1.json
  def update
    respond_to do |format|
      if @task.update(task_params)
        format.html { redirect_to home_url }
        format.json { render :home_url, status: :ok, location: @task }
      else
        format.html { render :home_url }
        format.json { render json: @task.errors, status: :unprocessable_entity }
      end
    end
  end

  # DELETE /tasks/1
  # DELETE /tasks/1.json
  def destroy
    current_user.tasks.where(id: params[:task][:task_ids])
    respond_to do |format|
      format.html { redirect_to home_url }
      format.json { head :no_content }
    end
  end

  private
    # Use callbacks to share common setup or constraints between actions.
    def task_params
      params.require(:task).permit(:name, :position)
    end

  def find_task!
    @task = current_user.tasks.find(params[:id])
  end

  def find_project!
    @project = current_user.projects.find(params[:task][:project_id])
  end
end
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add the belongs to in the migrations as well.

```
class CreateProjects < ActiveRecord::Migration
  def change
    create_table :projects do |t|
      t.string :name

      t.belongs_to :user

      t.timestamps null: false
    end
  end
end

class CreateTasks < ActiveRecord::Migration
  def change
    create_table :tasks do |t|
      t.string :name
      t.datetime :deadline

      t.belongs_to :project

      t.timestamps null: false
    end
  end
end
```

Comment: Should I also add has_many and has_many_through relations to migrations? @lassvi

Comment: Well,that solved this problem,but i still have the problem I've mentioned [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36060338/make-unique-object-in-rails),ty anyway @lassvi